# How can I convert a Box<T> to &T?

Tags: rust, traits

How do I call a function that expects a trait object if I have a `Box<T>` instead? In other words:

```
trait T { ... }

fn func(t: &T) { ... }

fn some_other_func() {
    b: Box<T>; // Provided

    // These work, but is there a better way?
    func( &*b );                // 1
    func( Borrow::borrow(&b) ); // 2
}
```

Both 1 and 2 seem wrong. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`&*foo` is called a "reborrow", and is idiomatic.

Comment: Alrighty then. I guess I was scared off just because it looked so very wrong to my poor C++-trained eyes. Thanks!