# What does “&*” do in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I encountered this block of code while reading documentation from a Rust library:

```
for (ent, pos, vel) in (&*entities, &mut pos_storage, &vel_storage).join() {
    println!("Processing entity: {:?}", ent);
    *pos += *vel;
}
```

What does `&*entities` do here? From what I can tell it’s dereferencing `entities` and then referencing it again. But why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an explicit reborrow and it's a common idiom that pops up in Rust from time to time.

- `&` in an expression only has one meaning: it takes an expression (which must be a [place expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51346943/3650362)) of type `T` and borrows a reference to it of type `&T`.
- For references, `*` does the opposite of `&` -- it takes a reference (`&T`) and makes a place expression of type `T`. But `*` can mean different things with different kinds of pointers, since you can override it by implementing `Deref`. Because `*` ties in some compiler magic that [automatically dereferences the return value of `Deref::deref`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31624743/1233251), you can borrow the result of `*`, turning it back into a plain reference, by using the `&` operator.

So `&*foo` is a way of explicitly reborrowing "any kind of pointer to `T`" as a `&T`, and is the equivalent of manually calling `Deref::deref(&foo)`.

(The above explanation also works for `&mut` borrows -- just replace `&` with `&mut` and `Deref` with `DerefMut`.)

It's not clear in the example you link what `entities` is, but it's probably some kind of smart pointer, where the `join()` method requires a plain reference. For another example where this is required, consider using [`[&str]::concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) to concatenate a `String` with some `&str`s:

```
// I want to concatenate this with some other strings
let s = String::from("Amelia");
// The following won't compile: you can't make an array of &str and String
assert_eq!(["Hello", ", ", s].concat(), "Hello, Amelia");    // WRONG
// However, &*s takes a reference to the str pointed to by s.
assert_eq!(["Hello", ", ", &*s].concat(), "Hello, Amelia");  // OK
```

### See also

- [Is there a difference between slicing and an explicit reborrow when converting Strings to &strs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33860750/3650362)
- [Box<T> to &T in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084849/boxt-to-t-in-rust/32085042#32085042)