# Get a &T from Box<T> in pattern

Tags: rust

Is there any way to create a `&str` binding from a `Box<str>`?

```rs
fn takes_str_ref(_: &str) {}

fn example(boxed: Box<str>) {
    let /* bind to "inner" */ = boxed;

    takes_str_ref(inner);
}
```

I am binding a struct with many `Box<str>` and it's kind of annoying to spam `.as_ref()` everywhere.

Comment: As a side note (or maybe even the answer), you can pass `&boxed` directly to `takes_str_ref` due to deref coercion.

Comment: https://media1.tenor.com/m/KsvZ1G5XL1UAAAAC/drake-computer.gif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no syntax currently to extract the inner value of a `Box` *using only a pattern* since `Box` is not "destructable".

There is this syntax, which is close:

```
let ref inner = *boxed;
```

But technically the `*` is doing the hard work of dereferencing the `Box<str>` into a `str`, and `ref` is just used to stick the `&` back on.

There is the unstable [`box_patterns`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29641) feature which would look like this:

```
let box ref inner = boxed;
```

However, I believe it is unlikely that this will reach stabilization since a [`deref_patterns`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87121) feature would be more widely applicable. However, the latter is currently not available even on nightly.

---

Besides that though, getting a `&T` from a `Box<T>` can be even easier than `.as_ref()` or a pattern:

- you can use `&*boxed` to explicitly get a reference to the inner value, or
- you can often use `&boxed` directly due to [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#deref-coercion):

  ```
  fn takes_str_ref(_: &str) {}

  fn example(boxed: Box<str>) {
      takes_str_ref(&boxed);
  }
  ```

Similar:

- [How can I convert a Box<T> to &T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32084849/how-can-i-convert-a-boxt-to-t)
- [How to convert a boxed trait into a trait reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218474/how-to-convert-a-boxed-trait-into-a-trait-reference)